# How to import data into MySQL from /var/lib/mysql-files

Tags: mysql

I copied an sql text file into /var/lib/mysql-files directory but the command:

```
 >mysql -u root -p < /var/lib/mysql-files/test.sql
```

but I get the error:

```
 bash: /var/lib/mysql-files/test.sql: Permission denied
```

The file has permissions set to 0744.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL dump for this.

**For creating a backup use:**

```
mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql
```

**For restoring a version use:**

```
mysql -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that when I try to re-import the file I get permission errors. I understood that I cannot import from any directory, but just from those considered to be secure by MySQL by default the /var/lib/mysql-files directory.

Comment: You can use this from any folder.  You might be getting the error due to the permissions in that folder. Try with `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, you're right. I was confused by the LOAD DATA from a file.